# Create custom dimension attribute in Visual Studio - SSAS

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssas, mdx, olap, cube

I'm creating a cube using Visual Studio 2015 and I want to explore it in different ways. Additionally, I'd like to use a reporting tool such as PowerBi (no other tools - unfortunately) - so I can't expose named sets directly with live connection.

I'd like to find a way to create a custom dimension attribute using calculations, aggregating all attributes dealing with a specific constraint.
I created several calculated measures, and I created a named set (exposed indirectly to PowerBi using a flag measure as visual filter) including all attributes of a dimension on a per-calculated specific measure basis, as an example

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET CURRENTCUBE.[TopX]
AS TopCount([Dim].[Dim].[All].CHILDREN, X, [Measures].[CalcMeasure]);
```

and it works. Now I'd like to understand the way I can obtain an attribute dimension called 'GTTopX', knowing that I can build it using the MDX command

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Dim].[Dim].GTTopX
AS (AGGREGATE({EXCEPT([Dim].[Dim].[All].CHILDREN, TopX)})), 
VISIBLE = 1  ;
```

Isn't it a dimension? I can use it in Visual Studio only as a "equal" filter, and when I try to include a measure in the browser this error message appears:

> A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members

However, if I try declaring it directly querying the cube using SSMS and then performing a select in this way

```
WITH MEMBER [Dim].[Dim].[GTTopX] AS
AGGREGATE(EXCEPT([Dim].[Dim].[All].Children, [TopX]))
SELECT [Measures].[CalcMeasureRandom] ON ROWS, [Dim].[Dim].[GTTopX] ON COLUMNS FROM [Cube]
```

the query gives me the correct result, showing the selected "dimension attribute" called as "GTTopX" .

How can I perform the same thing in Visual Studio?

Comment: It is not a dimension, you have just create, via `Aggregate`, a _single_ calculated member `[Dim].[Dim].[GTTopX]` which will be part of the existing dimension.

Comment: Ok, but I wanna show in Power Bi this particular dimension attribute as done using MDX query. How can I do it?
It works if included in a new named set but "GTTopX" doesn't appear as an additional dimension in Power Bi.